# Laravel: View not included in email content

Tags: email, laravel-4

I am using the [BeautyMail](https://github.com/snowfire/beautymail) package to send an email, which is sent successfully via `stmp.gmail.com`. I found out that the content of `emails.welcome` (welcome.blade.php) is not included, the email delivered is empty. 
Below is my code;

```
$data = array(
    'LastName' => 'ABC Widget', // Company name
    'senderName' => 'ABC Widget', // Company name
    'reminder' => 'You’re receiving this because you’re an awesome ABC Widgets customer or subscribed via <a href="http://www.abcwidgets.com/" style="color: #a6a6a6">our site</a>',
    'unsubscribe' => null,
    'address' => '87 Street Avenue, California, USA',

    'twitter' => 'http://www.facebook.com/abcwidgets',
    'facebook' => 'http://twitter.com/abcwidgets',
    'flickr' => 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/abcwidgets'
);

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from( 'johnny@gmail.com', 'John Doe' );
    $message->to('Suzanne@yahoo.com', 'Suzanne Doe')->subject('Testing Messages');
});
```

**VIEW**

```
@extends('beautymail::templates.widgets')

@section('content')

@include('beautymail::templates.widgets.articleStart')

    <h4 class="secondary"><strong>Hello World</strong></h4>
    <p>This is a test</p>

@include('beautymail::templates.widgets.articleEnd')


@include('beautymail::templates.widgets.newfeatureStart')

    <h4 class="secondary"><strong>Hello World again</strong></h4>
    <p>This is another test</p>

@include('beautymail::templates.widgets.newfeatureEnd')


@stop
```

No error was reported. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying removing the `BeautyMail` package and testing it. When I tried using the `BeautyMail` package, I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Beautymail have Ruby dependencies. I do think one of them fails which renders the empty email.

This issue has more details:
https://github.com/Snowfire/Beautymail/issues/2

Remove the inliner found in the service provider to remove the ruby dep.

Comment: Oh! I have removed them but will get it a shot cause I love the beautymail thingy. Thanks